# How to change the version of ubuntu i'm using on a dual booted preloaded windows 8 and linux system

Tags: 14.04, 14.10

How can I change the version of ubuntu I'm using on a dual booted ubuntu and windows 8 system (pre-loaded) with uef. Can I just update like via the software center or do I have to create a live usb again ( which was tedious initially). Thank you in anticipation of your response.

Comment: Could you edit your post on what your upgrading from and to.

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade from the software center, however ....

Before you upgrade , back up your data on BOTH OS in the event of a failure.

Also, although upgrades usually go well, but, they can fail or give problems. If you come across serious problems, it is usually faster to do a fresh install rather then debug a failed upgrade.

If you re-install, your data in /home will be preserves as long as you do NOT format the home directory.